# movieclip sending it to another frame

Tags: actionscript-3

iv made a colouring game and i want to make it so you can save the drawing (a Movieclip) and send it to another frame or scene, iv been looking into how it may be possible and it looks like it can be done with bitmapdata but i don't know how to even go about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to name your save button, and add a click listener to it.

```
// create the BitmapData that you'll be drawing to, give it the same dimensions 
var savedImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(holder.width, holder.height, false, 0xFFFFFF);

// add a click listener to your save button
saveBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onSave);
function onSave(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    // need to apply a transformation matrix because holder's origin is centered
    var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.translate(holder.width * .5, holder.height * .5);

    // clear out any existing image on savedImage
    savedImage.fillRect(savedImage.rect, 0xFFFFFF);

    // draw the holder onto the savedImage bitmapdata, using the transform matrix
    savedImage.draw(holder, matrix, null, null, null, true);
}
```

From there on out, you can pass your `savedImage` `BitmapData` to a `Bitmap` instance:

```
var savedBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(savedImage);
```

As long as `savedBitmap` is in the correct scope, you can add it to the display list on another frame:

```
addChild(savedBitmap);
```

Comment: If the BitmapData is not transparent: BitmapData(holder.width, holder.height, false, 0xFFFFFFFF) then there's no alpha bit available and the extra alpha bit in this is irrelevant: 0xFFFFFFFF. It should be 0xFFFFFF.  It is quite relevant since the presence of the alpha bit in your code lines imply that the alpha bit is available when it's not (instantiation + fillRect).

Comment: it works!! thank you could you example the code i want to understand it

Comment: savedImage.draw(holder, matrix, null, null, null, true);  i dont understand

Comment: Nizray, please reference the documentation for `BitmapData.draw` to understand what all the arguments are for the method: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()

Comment: Not sure why an extraneous (yet harmless) alpha bit would warrant a downvote, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I edited the answer just in case it might confuse others who stumble upon this.

Comment: thank you for your help marcela i would vote up on it if i had the rep it seems like a perfect answer to me

Comment: @Marcela could i ask you to look at another problem, im having problem with this hittestobject and i cant understand why its going wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488381/as3-hittestobject-not-working-dont-understand-why