# as3 hittestobject not working, dont understand why

Tags: actionscript-3

the collision not working i cant understand why, i put collision movieclips in the object and it doesnt seem to recognise one of the but does with the other, sorry for the confusing way of stating the problem if you play the game you will understand. im open to changing the way collision works too as long as it works ill be super happy

Comment: try to post a small example of code people can examine. this means people will be able to easily follow the logic without needing to install/use flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain. When You click "Down" or "Up" hero (box_MC) collide with both doors "Top_Door" and "Bottom_Door". Inside "bang" function at first checking collision with "Bottom_Door", so, hero always go down (.y += 100) and second condition (Top_Door) never will be true. How to fix this? Add variable `var lastAction:String;`. This variable will store last action: "up" or "down". Inside "down_MC_P" function initialize this variable by "down". Inside "up_MC_P" — "up". Next, replace the first condition to this `if (box_MC.hitTestObject(cycle[i].Bottom_Door) && lastAction == "down")` and second: `if(box_MC.hitTestObject(cycle[i].Top_Door) && lastAction == "up")`. That's all.

Comment: thank you for the reply and explaining why its not working but it still seems to do the same thing, one of the collisions work but the other doesn't.

Comment: I checked code before write comment. All should work. All my code You can see here: https://gist.github.com/subdan/31721de4e8b9ba5d7bde. Try to copy & paste.